# Mockito, what does @Mock really do to object

Tags: android, unit-testing, mocking, mockito, mockito-kotlin

As I understood, Mockito @Mock created a stub with empty methods or methods that otherwise return a default object for each type.  On contrary to @Spy which wraps the instance so that you use the actual implementation but still be able to mock certain methods.

However, I have a code such as:

```
@Mock
private lateinit var context: Context
@Mock
private lateinit var mockConfig: ConfigUtil
```

And whenever I debug a test I have `context` being a `Context@MockitoMock` instance, and `mockConfig` a real `ConfigUtil` instance,  therefore, calling any `mockConfig` method executes the real `ConfigUtil` implementation.

So, does Mockito only stub methods which are not on the build ? (such as Android classes).

--- Q2 ---

Is it a good practice to use @Mock in an object which is meant to test the real method implementation? or only on the dependencies that the instance uses.

In other words, If I create the `ConfigUtil` class, and the test suite is for that class, does it make any sense to create a @Mock instance of that class?

Comment: Which version and what dependency of mockito are you using (pure mockito / mockito-kotlin)? I guess that `mockito`is unable to mock `ConfigUtil` and fails silently. In that case you might end up with a real instance. You might want to add more information regarding that class to your question.

Comment: Regarding Q2: You should not mock the class under test. Spying is (best used) for legacy code that you are not allowed to change. So, no - it does not make sense.

Comment: @second We are using `kotlin` in this case

Comment: Hey @htafoya, did you get an answer to this query? I came across the same today, and observed the same behaviour from Mockito. It could create a good mock class only for the interface-based objects - not for the ones not implementing Intercaes(I suppose ConfigUtil is one such class in your case).

Comment: @Raj I don't remember, this was at 2019 when I was starting to learn Mockito. There seems to be no reason for that behaviour to happen, probably the runner was not applied or a missenterpretation of the debug output.